# How do I make a SelectInput which is part of the filter to be displayed by default?

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest, react-admin

I have an admin-on-rest system that shows a page with a list, and I have 2 fields in the filter, one (q - free text search) that I want to always display, and the second one is a status-select, which I want do allow the user to remove (and then appear in the 'add filter' list) but I want it to initially be displayed (so that the inital/default view is filtered to only a specific status) with the 'x' icon next to it so that the user will be able to remove this value, or to change it to see whatever other status filtering they want

could not find the way to do so...

Answer (score 0):

It's explained in the List [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#filters): you can add an `alwaysOn` prop to the filters you'd like to be always displayed.

```
const PostFilter = (props) => (
    <Filter {...props}>
        <TextInput label="Search" source="q" alwaysOn />
        <TextInput label="Title" source="title" defaultValue="Hello, World!" />
    </Filter>
);

export const PostList = (props) => (
    <List {...props} filters={<PostFilter />}>
        ...
    </List>
);
```

In order to set a default value for a filter, you also have to set the `filterDefaultValues` prop on the `List` component:

```
const PostFilter = (props) => (
    <Filter {...props}>
        <TextInput label="Search" source="q" alwaysOn />
        <BooleanInput source="is_published" alwaysOn />
        <TextInput source="title" defaultValue="Hello, World!" />
    </Filter>
);

export const PostList = (props) => (
    <List {...props} filters={<PostFilter />} filterDefaultValues={{ is_published: true }}>
        ...
    </List>
);
```

Comment: I know the alwaysOn setting, I don't want it to be always-on, I want it to be on-by-default, and removable.
Setting it to be alwaysOn, will not allow user to remove this filter

Comment: Then just use the `filterDefaultValues` prop.